# Что в этом контексте значит “детский тренер до пояса”?

Tags: значения

Фрагмент статьи:

> Февраль 2015 года. Из витринок, щедро расставленных в тучные годы вдоль городских улиц, исчезла реклама коммерческая; мутные пустующие стекла перемежаются рекламой социальной: **детский тренер до пояса**, да текст, что, мол, за десять лет детская смертность от наркотиков возросла в 42 раза (хм, еще один из вариантов вопроса на известный ответ…). В тон этому и прогнозы Минэкономразвития – там рассчитывают на «сокращение физического импорта на 33,9% при среднегодовом курсе более 60 руб. за $1, падении инвестиций на 13,7% (отток капитала составит $115 млрд) и реальных зарплат на 9,6%».

Источник: [Компьютерра, *Солнце живое начинает бить солнце консервированное!*](http://www.computerra.ru/114349/solntse-zhivoe-nachinaet-bit-solntse-konservirovannoe/)

Я обычно слова *тренер* и *пояс* понимаю, ну здесь не знаю о чем идет речь. Ответы пожалуйста по-русски (английскую версию ответа можете конечно добавить если что).

Comment: Имеется в виду изображение, на котором видна только верхняя половина человека.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Так как ему противопоставляется «да текст», имеется в виду явно фото детского тренера по пояс (waist-up).

Answer (score 3):

Я хоть и русский, но значения этого выражения не понимаю, да и сам текст очень тяжел для восприятия. Возможно, имеется ввиду, что изображение тренера на плакате по высоте от земли до пояса.

Answer (score 1):

"Тренер до пояса" может означать, что он даёт начальную подготовку до получения спортивного разряда - "пояса"

Comment: Теоретически да, но здесь из контекста явствует другое.